# jQuery removeClass and addClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I working on a website for playing a game on a board of variable size. I'm creating it in a for loop, which is working the way I want it to except for changing and removing the class in the click listener. What should happen is the class "empty" should be removed, then either "black" or "white" be added, and then the proper CSS will be applied. I added the console.log() statements and I'm getting what I expect, but the class is remaining the same (addClass and removeClass both not doing anything). I added the return false because I saw the suggestion on another question, but it didn't seem to do anything. What am I missing?

```
for(var i = 0; i < dim; i++) { // x
  for(var j = 0; j < dim; j++) { // y
    board.append('<circle id="'+ id +'" class="empty" cx="'+ (start+gap*j) +'" cy="'+ (start+gap*i) +'" r="'+ (radius) +'"/>');

    $(document).on('click', '#'+id, function() {
      console.log("clicked with color " + color);
      console.log(this);
      $(this).removeClass("empty");
      $(this).addClass(color); // I also have tried this with just "white" or "black" instead of a variable
      console.log(this);
      return false; 
    });

    id++;
  }
}
```

What is logged when I click on the circle with id=0:

```
<circle id="0" class="empty" cx="8" cy="8" r="4.75">
<circle id="0" class="empty" cx="8" cy="8" r="4.75">
```

Here's the relevant CSS:

```
circle.empty {
  stroke: none;
  fill-opacity: 0;
}

circle.white {
  stroke: black;
  fill: white;
  fill-opacity: 1;
}

circle.black {
  stroke: black;
  fill: black;
  fill-opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Don't put your click function inside foor loop.

Comment: since the number of circles might change, where would I put my click function if not in the for loop that creates the circles?

Comment: You can use general class instead of id

Comment: would that still only target the individual circle that's clicked?

Comment: Yes check the console log of my answer when you use $(this) it will return relevent target

Answer (score 0):

Do not use click function inside the for loop and instead of `ID` use genral class `.circle` like below,

```js
$(document).on('click', '.circle', function() {
  $(this).removeClass("empty");
  $(this).addClass('red');
  console.log(`${$(this).attr('id')} - ${$(this).attr('class')}`);
});

for(var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
   $('#wrapper').append(`<div id="${j}" class="circle empty">Click Me</div>`);    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: where would I put my click function? I'm creating the circles in a for loop, since the number of them will change, so to give them all a click function wouldn't I need to use a loop?

Comment: Put click function outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

My english is not good at all.

You cant write same "id" attr on circle. It doesnt work when you click circle.

Then change like this.

```
$(document).on('click', '.'+id, function() {
   // some logic here
});
```